# Find an open set $B$ such that $g^{-1}(B)$ is not open

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

[image]

I cannot understand part ii) in this solution. I cannot see the significance of arbitrarily close to 0 points for which $|sin(\frac{1}{x_n})|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our goal is to show that $g^{-1}(B)$ fails to be open because, although $0 \in g^{-1}(B)$, no open neighborhood of $0$ lies inside the set $g^{-1}(B)$.

So, we want to show that for any $\delta > 0$, the set $(-\delta,\delta)$ (the neighborhood of $0$ of radius $\delta$) is not a subset of $g^{-1}(B)$.  That is, for every such $\delta$, there exists some $x \in (-\delta,\delta)$ for which $g(x) \notin (-1/2,1/2)$.

In particular, for any such $\delta$, we can choose an $x = x_n$ with $|x_n| < \delta$.  So, $x_n \in (-\delta,\delta)$, but $g(x_n) = 1 \notin (-\delta,\delta)$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $g^{-1}(B)$ was open, it should contain an $\varepsilon$-ball with center $0$ for some $\varepsilon>0$, since $0\in g^{-1}(B)$. But for all $\varepsilon>0$ you find a point in this ball, which maps to $1$, hence the ball cannot lie in $g^{-1}((-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$!